# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Tags: python, json, text, encoding, tweets

I am trying to extract the text from a .json file which i extracted. The problem is, that every time I am trying I am getting the aforementioned error(title). Here is my code:

```
import json

with open('grtwe.json.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    print(json.dumps(tweet, indent=4))
```

Also tweets are greek.

The first line of my .json file is this

```
{"place": null, "geo": null, "source": "<a href=\"" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Lite</a>", "id_str": "967369573505921024", "favorite_count": 0, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "favorited": false, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "full_text": "RT @documentonews:#Novartis_gate\n\u0391\u03c0\u03bf\u03ba\u03ac\u03bb\u03c5\u03c8\u03b7-\u03c3\u03bf\u03ba: \u039a\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c4\u03c1\u03af\u03c4\u03bf\u03c2 \u03bd\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03cc\u03c2 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf \u03b4\u03c1\u03cc\u03bc\u03bf \u03c4\u03b7\u03c2 Novartis, \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf Documento \u03c0\u03bf\u03c5 \u03ba\u03c5\u03ba\u03bb\u03bf\u03c6\u03bf\u03c1\u03b5\u03af \u03c4\u03b7\u03bd \u039a\u03c5\u03c1\u03b9\u03b1\u03ba\u03ae | https\u2026", "truncated": false, "user": {"notifications": false, "is_translator": false, "profile_image_url": "", "profile_background_tile": false, "id_str": "387685829", "geo_enabled": false, "profile_image_url_https":"", "statuses_count": 47093, "screen_name": "satrapis21", "is_translation_enabled": false, "followers_count": 1692, "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_background_image_url_https": "", "url": null, "follow_request_sent": false, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", "profile_use_background_image": true, "profile_link_color": "D02B55", "profile_text_color": "3E4415", "description":"\u03be\u03b5\u03bd\u03bf\u03b4\u03bf\u03c7\u03bf\u03c2 \u03b3\u03ba\u03bf\u03c5\u03bb\u03b1\u03b3\u03ba \u03b5\u03c0\u03b5\u03bd\u03b4\u03c5\u03c4\u03b7\u03c2", "profile_background_color": "352726", "id": 387685829, "friends_count": 1689, "favourites_count": 3380, "created_at": "Sun Oct 09 14:01:48 +0000 2011", "default_profile": false, "translator_type": "none", "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "99CC33", "default_profile_image": false, "listed_count": 39, "profile_banner_url": "","following": false, "utc_offset": 7200, "protected": false, "verified": false, "name": "\u03ba\u03bf\u03c5\u03bb\u03b7\u03c2satrapis", "profile_background_image_url":"", "time_zone": "Vilnius", "lang": "el", "contributors_enabled": false,"location": ""}, "metadata": {"result_type": "recent", "iso_language_code": "el"}, "id": 967369573505921024, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "created_at": "Sat Feb 2412:04:13 +0000 2018", "display_text_range": [0, 140], "retweeted": false, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "lang": "el", "coordinates": null, "retweeted_status": {"place": null, "geo": null, "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", "id_str": "967369433864863744", "favorite_count": 13, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "favorited": false, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false,"full_text": "#Novartis_gate\n\u0391\u03c0\u03bf\u03ba\u03ac\u03bb\u03c5\u03c8\u03b7-\u03c3\u03bf\u03ba: \u039a\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c4\u03c1\u03af\u03c4\u03bf\u03c2 \u03bd\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03cc\u03c2 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf \u03b4\u03c1\u03cc\u03bc\u03bf \u03c4\u03b7\u03c2 Novartis, \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf Documento \u03c0\u03bf\u03c5 \u03ba\u03c5\u03ba\u03bb\u03bf\u03c6\u03bf\u03c1\u03b5\u03af \u03c4\u03b7\u03bd \u039a\u03c5\u03c1\u03b9\u03b1\u03ba\u03ae | ","truncated": false, "user": {"notifications": false, "is_translator": false, "profile_image_url": "", "profile_background_tile": false, "id_str": "795738344906952705", "geo_enabled": false, "profile_image_url_https": "", "statuses_count": 39383, "screen_name": "documentonews", "is_translation_enabled": false, "followers_count": 4607, "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_background_image_url_https": null, "url": "", "follow_request_sent": false, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_use_background_image": true, "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_text_color": "333333", "description": "H \u039d\u03ad\u03b1 \u039c\u03b5\u03b3\u03ac\u03bb\u03b7 \u039a\u03c5\u03c1\u03b9\u03b1\u03ba\u03ac\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03b7 \u0395\u03c6\u03b7\u03bc\u03b5\u03c1\u03af\u03b4\u03b1", "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA", "id": 795738344906952705, "friends_count": 180, "favourites_count": 0, "created_at": "Mon Nov 07 21:23:00 +0000 2016", "default_profile": true, "translator_type": "none", "entities": {"url": {"urls": [{"url": "", "display_url": "documentonews.gr", "expanded_url": "", "indices": [0, 23]}]}, "description": {"urls": []}}, "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "default_profile_image": false, "listed_count": 69, "profile_banner_url": "", "following": false,"utc_offset": 7200, "protected": false, "verified": false, "name": "Documento", "profile_background_image_url": null, "time_zone": "Athens", "lang": "en", "contributors_enabled": false, "location": "Greece"},"metadata": {"result_type": "recent", "iso_language_code": "el"}, "id": 967369433864863744, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "created_at": "Sat Feb 24 12:03:40 +0000 2018", "display_text_range": [0, 162],"retweeted": false, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "lang": "el", "coordinates": null, "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Novartis_gate", "indices": [0, 14]}], "user_mentions": [], "symbols": [], "urls": [{"url": "", "display_url": "Documentonews.gr", "expanded_url": "", "indices": [115, 138]}, {"url": "", "display_url":"documentonews.gr/article/apokal\u2026", "expanded_url": "", "indices": [139, 162]}]}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "retweet_count": 10}, "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Novartis_gate", "indices": [19, 33]}], "user_mentions": [{"name": "Documento", "id": 795738344906952705,"screen_name": "documentonews", "id_str": "795738344906952705", "indices": [3, 17]}], "symbols": [], "urls": []}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "retweet_count": 10}
```

The rest of the file contains such records.

Comment: Sounds like the data in your file isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Go to jsonlint.com and paste the first line of your file.

Comment: What does the json file look like? You're only extracting the first line? Is the first line, on it's own, valid JSON?

Comment: In general, nobody will be able to answer a question like this without being able to see the contents of `grtwe.json.json`. (Or, better, a smaller and simpler file that generates the same error—see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.) In this case, people can _guess_, because using `f.readline()` instead of `f.read()` is unusual—most `.json` files are a single JSON object, rather than a sequence of single-line JSON objects—but that's still just a guess.

Comment: @Barmar According to the site you provided it is a valid .json

Comment: Maybe there's a hidden character (e.g. BOM) at the beginning of the file. View it with a hex editor.

Comment: @Barmar No hidden character unfortunately. Could the encoding of the file cause this error?

Comment: It's curious that you're only reading 1 line, but the error message says the problem is on line 2. Sounds like there may be a problem with the newline encoding.

Comment: u have any suggestions probably?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you are trying to only parse the *first line* of the file (since you call `json.loads()` on `f.readline()`). It sounds more probable, that your *whole* file is JSON - in which case you want to pass the whole thing in one go.

```
with open('grtwe.json.json', 'r') as f:
    tweet = json.loads(f.read())
    print(json.dumps(tweet, indent=4))
```

However, I obviously can't check without the file!

Comment: I have edited my original post. The rest of the .json consists of such records.

Answer (score 0):

loads() triggered the error!
and so the problem is in the json file which appears to be not in the json
format.
you need to get sure that the json file is in the correct json format
you could go to https://jsonlint.com and past your json string there
and it will tell you if it is in the right format.